# Why doesn't CAST( AS ) sometimes work on BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, type-conversion

I tried two queries:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS DATE) = CURRENT_DATE() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
```

and

```
SELECT CASE WHEN DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) = CURRENT_DATE() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
```

The first query fails in Legacy SQL but not in Standard SQL, while the second query works. (Standard SQL is currently not covered by SLA.)

Comment: Standard SQL is covered by the BigQuery SLA as well. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with first query in Legacy SQL:

1. CAST(... AS DATE) in Legacy SQL only works on strings, while CURRENT_TIMESTAMP returns TIMESTAMP type
2. CURRENT_DATE in Legacy SQL is misleadingly returns STRING, not DATE :(

Both of these problems are indeed fixed with Standard SQL

Answer (score 1):

Legacy SQL has [limited support for DATE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/data-types#legacy_sql_data_types). For more information, see [Civil time in legacy SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/data-types#civil-time)

So, if you need to be in Legacy SQL - you should use second query in your case with DATE() function